# MySQL: conduct a basic search

Tags: python, mysql

I have a names table in my database and I would wish to conduct a fuzzy search on it for example my database contains:

```
Name         ID
John Smith   1
Edward Smith 2
Gabriel Gray 3
Paul Roberts 4
```

At the moment when I search the database via python I can only do exact match searching. But I would like to be able to do fuzzy searching where by I can search for the name "smith" and bring back John Smith and Edward Smith.

Comment: Do you only need it to be case-insensitive? Or you actually need it to return matches for similar strings (ie: search for smiht brings back John Smith and Edward Smith)?

Comment: return similar strings, so case sesnsitivity required

Comment: because "fuzzy search" usually means this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: Ok, so what is the term i'm looking for to describe my problem by?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simplest form, you'd use the `LIKE` comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%smith%';
```

More elaborate searches can de done with FULLTEXT index (large amounts of text), `SOUNDEX()` (works on words in the english language, matching on other languages is everything from 'somewhat workable' to 'terrible'), levenshtein distance of words etc.

Comment: To add to that, you can use case-insensitive comparison in MySQL if you select the appropriate collation (one that has the _ci suffix)

Comment: Thank you, the simpliest form id what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
import MySQLdb
search_str = 'smith'
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="me",passwd="pw",db="mydb")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE %s", '%' + search_str + '%')
c.fetchall()
c.close()
conn.close()
```